# Floating elements dropping out of container in IE7 and sometimes in WebKit browsers too

Tags: css, webkit, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have following CSS code and my floats are dropping out of their containers. Firefox doesn't have this problem. What could be reason for this behaviour?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftmenu">
        ... some stuff here ...
    </div>
    <div class="rightmenu">
        <div style="float: right; text-align: right;">
            <button class="ui-state-disabled ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> Button 1 </button>
            <button class="ui-state-disabled ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> Button 2 </button>
            <button class="ui-state-disabled ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> Button 3 </button>
            <button class="ui-state-disabled ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> Button 4 </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting.  It should happen in Firefox too.

Comment: Nobody seems to understand what the problem is. Which container are the floats dropping out of? A couple of the solutions below will fix the problem 'rightmenu' collapsing but either you are applying them wrong or we are all answering the wrong question.  Do you have a link to a live site?

Comment: Emily's right. A live site or at least a complete example would be very helpful. At the very least you might be able to provide some screen shots.

Comment: Agreed. I think some example screenshots in several browsers would help us all alot, or a link to a live site.

Comment: -1 to this question. It's not clear. Anyway, a floated box is taken out of the flow, so it doesn’t affect the block-level boxes around it, and is normal that it drops out of its container. In any browser, of course. You should explain better your problem. If it appears only in IE it could be not a float but a width problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The container, in your case "div.container", will not be able to calculate the correct height of itself once its children are floated. If there are any child blocks that are not floated, the container will use the height of the tallest one among them.

A container with both of its child blocks floated is common anyway. There are certain ways to fix this. Consider the approaches summarized by QuirksMode the best. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

So, to solve your problem, just add this in your CSS file.

```
div.container { overflow: auto; width: 100%; }
```

NOTICE: The width value could be any value you want. but it is obligated to trigger the HasLayout behavior in IE[67]

Another work around. You may use an extra div:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Add this after `div.right` in `div.container`.

However, there is better way to do this. Add an `.clearfix` utility class in your CSS:

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Add `clearfix` to the class attribute of `div.container`.

Comment: Giving the container an explicit width was the key for me. Very helpful answer, thank you!

Comment: The width seemed to do it for me too! Elegant answer @nil

Answer (score 2):

In some rare case the

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

will not work because in such case div use default line-height and default font-size

Put this class in CSS

```
.clear { clear: both; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; height: 0px; overflow:hidden; }
```

and use it in code

```
<div class="leftmenu">
... some stuff here ...
</div>
<div class="rightmenu">
... some stuff here ...
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the bottom of the #rightmenu div:

```
<span style="clear:both;"></span>
```

The clear both style ends the float from both the left and right sides.  Putting the clear just after the floated element prevents float leakage by terminating the float effect to within the container's parent element.

Answer (score 0):

The div rightmenu has no height because it contains only floated elements which do not have a height themselves.

To clear the float use

```
<div class="rightmenu" style="overflow:hidden;zoom:1;background-color:#ccc;">
```

The `overflow:hidden` will clear the float for firefox, safari and chrome. The `zoom:1` invokes [hasLayout](http://haslayout.net/haslayout) for ie6/ie7. The `background-color:#ccc` is just so you can see the div does contain the floats.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the "leftmenu" and "rightmenu" classes do, it's hard to work out your exact issue, but try adding `overflow: hidden;` to any element is NOT floated, but HAS floated children. i.e.: div.rightmenu in the example, and any other rules in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftmenu">
        ... some stuff here ...
    </div>
    <div class="rightmenu" style="padding-bottom: 5px !ie; border: 1px solid black;">
        <div style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                <button style="display: inline-block;" class="ui-state-disabled ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> Button 1 </button>
                <button class="ui-state-disabled ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> Button 2 </button>
                <button class="ui-state-disabled ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> Button 3 </button>
                <button class="ui-state-disabled ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> Button 4 </button>
        </div>
        <br style="clear: both;" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Does the trick.